# Sandwich Theorem for Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am to determine if the sequence converge or diverge, and find the limit in case of convergence.

$a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n-4}$

The solution manual states that I can apply the Sandwich Theorem, because $b_n \leq a_n \leq c_n$, where

$b_n=\frac{-1}{3n-4}$ and $c_n=\frac{1}{3n-4}$.

Here something is obviously lost to me, because when I calculate for n=0 and n=1, I get:

$b_0=.2,a_0=.2,c_0=-.2$ and $b_1=-1,a_1=1,c_1=1$, which does not agree with $b_n \leq a_n \leq c_n$.

Where is my logic failing?

Correction: It should say $(6n-5), not (3n-4)$

Comment: This inequality $b_n \le a_n \le c_n$ would only work for $n\ge 2$, because only then the denominator is positive.

Comment: Miel, thank you very much! That made me understand my error. Fantastic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the definition of limit, the limit of a sequence is mainly the behavior of tail. That is if you can show $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n>N$ the property is satisfied by $a_n,b_n,c_n$, then it's fine to use the theorem.

You can also interpret the above statement as if you define $b_n=a_{n+M}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ ( that is shift the original sequence by a finite number of elements), then $b_n$ and $a_n$ has the same convergence property. That is they convergent or divergent at the same time, and if they are convergent, they share the same limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, John. Could you explain the symbols used too, if you have time? I am just starting calculus and do not understand these.

Comment: @Akitirija $\exists$ means "there exists", $\forall$ means " for all". $\in$ means "in" that is "an element of"

Comment: Thank you very much, John!